# Make scheduled tasks with node-schedule (using forever) persist after a restart

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, backgroundworker, background-process, forever

I want to develop a node.js program that will be executed at a specific time using a job scheduler (node-schedule).
This program is running in the background using forever (node.js module).
Here's the content of my app.js :

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
```

~
 ~

```
var id =  request.body.id;
var scheduled = schedule.scheduledJobs;
if(scheduled[id]!=null){ 
//Tasks
}
else{ 
 scheduled[id].cancel;
 delete scheduled[id];
}
```

But if app.js is killed by any reason,
the `schedule` object is removed.
and sometimes app.js is restarted by forever.
how can I handle node-schedule objects ?

Comment: If i have to modify my code..
i also have to restart app.js...after that i can not have info of node-schedule's object.

Comment: You need to reassign, at the start of your app.js, every tasks that were scheduled before

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar problem recently and there are two solutions:
 1. Use actual cron
 2. Use database

I solved my problem by using database. Each time you are creating some event save it to database. In your app.js file when the application is starting make function reading the database and creating scheduled events accordingly.

The first option is better if you do not have dynamic tasks, you do not create new tasks or if they are always the same.